# Bluej - JButton Image Loading

Tags: java, image, swing, nullpointerexception, embedded-resource

Every time I am trying to load an image file to give an icon to my `JButton`, Java shows a null pointer exception.  I have Checked the directories The image is present.

Can you please help me out?

Here is my code.

```
jButton1.setIcon(new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/Users/Stallion/Yo/Key-50.png " )));
```

Comment: `"/Users/Stallion/Yo/Key-50.png "`  Remove the space character on the end of the string.  Is there *really* a `Users` directory inside your project class-path?  I think you've mistaken a class-path for a file system path.

Comment: There's a space at the end of the string. Try removing it. Please post the full stack trace when you ask for help resolving an error.

Comment: Okay Sir @AlessandroDaRugna Da

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same problem I fixed created a new package and put the images inside because when u export .jar the images come in the program

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pgt77.png]

Then i wrote

```
    JButton buttonNew = 
           new JButton(new ImageIcon(this.getClass().getResource("/res/new_con.gif")));
```

and it worked perfectly.